# AJAX, PHP, JSON & Query Strings: How to safely and effeciently pass variables?

Tags: php, ajax, json, query-string

I have a search page (search.php) that calls an AJAX load and loads the results into the #myresults DIV:

```
$('#myresults').load('results.php', {"q":"<?php echo urlencode($this->params['url']['q']); ?>","min":<?php echo urlencode($this->params['url']['min']); ?>,max:<?php echo urlencode($this->params['url']['max']); ?>});
```

The querystring looks like:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/search?q=test&min=50&max=100
```

results.php looks like this:

```
if (isset($data['q']) && isset($data['min']) && isset($data['max'])) {
 $q = urldecode($data['q']);
 $min = urldecode($data['min']);
 $max = urldecode($data['max']);
}
```

I'm grabbing the querystring values, then posting them to the results page.  Is URLEncode needed or should I use htmlspecialchars()?  I've seen JSON.stringify() and I'm just not sure how to "best" encode my data (so that it can't be "broken" by those manipulating the querystring) and post it safely to the backend for use in my backend php code.  I'm most concerned about apostrophes and quotes, how do i handle them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jQuery documentation the load() you will get the variables as POST:

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

So you should just treat it as a normal POST.

If you use the variables in a query for example you would use mysql_escape_string() to prevent MySQL injection.

Comment: But this isn't a normal POST, right?  What if a users has quotes in the querystring?, then the JSON data string is broken: `code`"q":"<?php echo $this->params['url']['q']; ?>"

Comment: So your question actually is how to safely implement user generated strings into a JSON object? I think addslashes() would be enough.

Comment: I ended up using addslashes() and it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to remove any characters you know are not allowed which you can do with `preg_replace`. If you can't do that `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` will work.

And of course escape the data before you search your database.